# System.IO File Расположение файла

Tags: c#, json, mvc

привет есть код

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"data.json");
```

файл расположен в одной папке с контролером но студия все равно ищет файл по `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\data.json' не найден.`
в чем прикол
Делал так

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"/Data/data.json");
```

Папка Data на одном уровне с папкой Controllers

все равно ошибка и ищет  в диск С
В чем прикол

Comment: "_В чем прикол_" - в том, что относительные пути зависят от текущей папки, которая может быть изменена любым методом неявно для вас.А символ / в начале пути означает путь относительно корневого каталога.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ControllerName/data.json"));
```

Comment: не робит не чего

Comment: `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Data/data.json")))` Вот так робит